# Why has the parameter of my Delphi function with PyDelphiWrapper always a fix wrong value?

Tags: delphi, python4delphi

I am using Python4Delphi and try to get the demo WrapDelphiDemo running.

What it should do is to calculate the amount of prime numbers for values up to 1000000.

The expected value is 78498 but when I let the demo code running I get 575843.

I found out that parameter value "MaxN" of the function is always a fix value of 8574564 instead the expected 1000000.

```
class function TDelphiFunctions.count_primes(MaxN: integer): integer;
var
  Count : integer;
begin
  Count := 0;
  ShowMessage(format('function parameter MaxN=%d is WRONG!!!! Should be 1000000!!!',[MaxN]));
  //MaxN := 1000000;
  TParallel.&For(2, MaxN, procedure(i: integer)
    begin
      if IsPrime(i) then
        AtomicIncrement(Count);
    end);
  Result := Count;
end;
```

I use Delphi Seattle with Win7.

Python4Delphi is the latest from GitHub.

I use the original demo code.

What I need to adapt is that with Seattle version I cannot use inline variable definition.

Does anyone have an idea what I can do?

Here the full code of MainForm:

```pascal
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls, SynEdit, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  PythonEngine, PythonGUIInputOutput, SynEditPythonBehaviour,
  SynEditHighlighter, SynEditCodeFolding, SynHighlighterPython, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  WrapDelphi;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    sePythonCode: TSynEdit;
    HeaderControl1: THeaderControl;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Splitter1: TSplitter;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    HeaderControl2: THeaderControl;
    mePythonOutput: TMemo;
    SynPythonSyn: TSynPythonSyn;
    SynEditPythonBehaviour: TSynEditPythonBehaviour;
    PythonEngine: TPythonEngine;
    PythonGUIInputOutput: TPythonGUIInputOutput;
    btnRun: TButton;
    PyDelphiWrapper: TPyDelphiWrapper;
    PythonModule: TPythonModule;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnRunClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  System.Rtti,
  System.Threading,
  System.Math;

type
  TDelphiFunctions = record
    class function count_primes(MaxN: integer): integer; static;
  end;

var
  DelphiFunctions: TDelphiFunctions;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Py : PPyObject;
begin
  Py := PyDelphiWrapper.WrapRecord(@DelphiFunctions, TRttiContext.Create.GetType(TypeInfo(TDelphiFunctions)) as TRttiStructuredType);
  PythonModule.SetVar('delphi_functions', Py);
  PythonEngine.Py_DecRef(Py);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnRunClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetPythonEngine.ExecString(UTF8Encode(sePythonCode.Text));
end;

function IsPrime(x: Integer): Boolean;
var
  q, i : integer;
begin
  if (x <= 1) then Exit(False);

  q := Floor(Sqrt(x));
  for i := 2 to q do
    if (x mod i = 0) then
      Exit(False);
  Exit(True);
end;

class function TDelphiFunctions.count_primes(MaxN: integer): integer;
var
  Count : integer;
begin
  Count := 0;
  ShowMessage(format('function parameter MaxN=%d is WRONG!!!! Should be 1000000!!!',[MaxN]));
  //MaxN := 1000000;
  TParallel.&For(2, MaxN, procedure(i: integer)
    begin
      if IsPrime(i) then
        AtomicIncrement(Count);
    end);
  Result := Count;
end;

end.
```

Comment: @Tom It's passed by an embedded Python instance which is executing code from the synedit control

Comment: The function is called in the python code. `from delphi_module import delphi_functions
from timeit import Timer
import math

def test():
    max_n = 1000000
    print(f'Number of primes between 0 and {max_n} = {delphi_functions.count_primes(max_n)}')

def main():
    print(f'Elapsed time: {Timer(stmt=test).timeit(1)} secs')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`

Comment: @Tom I think this question needs expertise in Pyrhon4Delphi

Comment: @David, ok, understood